# workflow to transform item fulfillment only when no back ordered items exist

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript

I've created a workflow that transforms and creates item fulfillment's when new Sales Orders are created. I have couple of conditions already set (listed below) but want to add one more condition, so the workflow only runs when no back orders quantities exist on the sales order. There's no NetSuite native field which holds the total back ordered quantity of sales order, so wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how this might be achievable?

Workflow runs after submit of new sales orders, with below conditions, and generates/transforms item fulfillment's. I need to add another condition to only trigger this workflow when no back orders quantities exist on the sales orders.

My current formula conditions:
{orderstatus.id}='B' and {location.id}=6

Answer (score 0):

I do not think what you are trying to achieve is possible using workflow alone. Reason being because you would need to scan all line items for any backorders before it can determine whether any backorders exist or not. Workflows (from my knowledge) cannot analyse data at item line level.

Consider writing a Suitescript (using the nlapiTransformRecord API) for this requirement instead.